# HTML input pattern that includes only specific numbers

Tags: html, input

I want the value 100, 200, 300, 400, 500 only to be valid in my input.
I don't even want value 101. So how should I write the pattern.

Comment: Could you use a drop-down list using the `select` tag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this to your element:

```
pattern="[1-5][0][0]"
```

for example:

```html
<form>
  <input type="text" pattern="[1-5][0][0]">
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest and safe way is to use Drop-down field with 
HTML Tag "select" and add "OPTION" values as 100, 200.

`<option value="100">100</option>`
 `<option value="200">200</option>`

this will minimize the typo error validation message to user.